# Is it possible to have a function that returns either Integer or Float in Golang?

Tags: go

I'd like to create a function which returns an integer value if a condition passes inside the function and a floating point number otherwise. How can I handle this with Go? Thank you!

Comment: You can return `interface{}`. Go is statically-typed at compile time. If your function could return one of two types, how would the caller work? It has to receive a value of one type.

Comment: What is your use case for doing that?

Comment: returning a median

Comment: If it's either a float or an Int then it's a float.

Comment: Just return a float, as @Ibu said , it being a float does not prevent that it's also an Integer. e.g.  return 3.0 , instead of 3.

Comment: Thank you that helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just have to return it as a float:

```
func doStuff(flag bool) float32 {
    if flag {
        return 1.1
    }
    return 1
}

func main() {
    num1 := doStuff(true)
    num2 := doStuff(false)
    fmt.Println("Num1: ", num1)
    fmt.Println("Num2: ", num2)
}
```

The only thing that matters is how you format it for displaying.

[Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/lp11-gXG5CM)

Comment: Note that you will lose precision when you return an integer as a float and the integer is a large number that cannot be fully expressed in the mantissa of a 32 bit float. In a `float32`, the number of significant bits to express the number are 23, whereas in an `int32` that's 31 bits. Integers with an absolute value greater than a few million will lose precision.

Comment: Here 32 was just an example and can be easily updated to float64. The point I was trying to make was not to use any complex type checking and simply return a float.

Answer (score 2):

That is not directly possible in Golang. In general, statically typed languages will usually do their best to prevent this scenario, because it makes type checking very difficult. The type checking is necessary because integer and floating point are inherently incompatible.

You could return `interface{}`. However, how will the caller know what you returned?

Answer (score 1):

Is this something that you are looking for?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func number(intOrFloat bool) interface{} {
    if intOrFloat { //return int if this flag is true
        return 5
    }
    return 5.5
}

func main() {
    printType(number(true))
    printType(number(false))
    printType("Nihanth")
}

func printType(value interface{}) {
    if number, ok := value.(int); ok {
        fmt.Printf("I have got an integer %d\n", number)
    } else if number, ok := value.(float64); ok {
        fmt.Printf("I have got float %f\n", number)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%+v is not integer or float", value)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to return a median of a slice. The value 2 for {1, 2, 3} and the value 2.5 for {1, 2, 3, 4}. I think I'll return a float in both cases as previous comments suggested. The interface{} thing looks a little bit overcomplicated for me as a beginner. Anyway, I appreciate your time!

Comment: gotcha. no problem.